# Why does Facebook graph require an access token for videos but not albums?

Tags: permissions, facebook-graph-api

Why does the Facebook graph API require an access token in order to access videos for my Facebook page:

- http://graph.facebook.com/valleyviewseek/videos

But doesn't require an access token when I try to access the page's albums and photos?

- http://graph.facebook.com/valleyviewseek/albums
- http://graph.facebook.com/473223039060/photos

Are videos under tighter security than albums and photos?  Did I do something in my Facebook fan page permission settings to open up albums and photos but not videos?  I don't see anything in the [API overview](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api) that suggests that these objects are any different from each other.

Is there any way to open up the videos so I don't need a token?

Answer (score 1):

You will notice that Page's videos requires a facebook account:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/

> videos | 
>   Available to everyone on Facebook |
>   An array of Video objects

Trying to find the solution to this myself.

See: [Applications for a Facebook page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760031/applications-for-a-facebook-page/4785643#4785643)

Answer (score 0):

I've been dealing with this issue only on videos as well, and found that you can use the page's access token.

That can be gathered easily via the graph explorer, simply select your app and then be sure to check permissions for "account" and "offline_access"**.  The call looks like this to render pages after those permissions have been granted (you must be admin of the page in question):

```
http://graph.facebook.com/<your facebook ID>/accounts
```

This can of course be scripted via an SDK, but I've found it easiest to just snag the access token directly out of the explorer's output.

Use the page access token in your videos object graph API call and you will get results.  Using PHP I've been referencing the video on the page via its object ID:

```
$graphCallParams = array("access_token" => <page access token gathered from above>);
$facebook->api('<video object id>', $graphCallParams);
```

**offline_access will make sure the page access token does not expire, but I still personally do not trust this, and have been thinking about writing a script that does periodic access token validity checks.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into an issue where Facebook is now requesting an access_token for public photo albums as well. Looks like in the last few days they have upped their security.