# Applications for a Facebook page

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-graph-api

- I own a page
- I own an application
- I added the application on the page (even though it does not appear on the application list of the page :/)

Is it possible to access the page's full feed and post messages from the application using the GraphAPI with the token of my application ?

I have full access to this page when using my user's token though.

I'm using [Koala](https://github.com/arsduo/koala/wiki) (in Ruby). Here's the snippet I'm using:

```
oauth = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new(FACEBOOK_APP_ID, FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET)
token = oauth.get_app_access_token
graph = Koala::Facebook::GraphAPI.new(token)
pp graph.get_connections(ENTRY_ID, "comments")
```

With this, I do not get all the comments on the ENTRY_ID.

Comment: what scripting language you are using? do you need an offline access?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your application has to be granted "admin" access to the page. More specifically the "manage_pages" privilege. As an admin of the page, you could grant the app the appropriate privileges.

Scroll down to the "Page Login" section on this page.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/